# generate RSA key for existing PemChain, OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I have a certificate in full Pem Chain from NO-IP for my application and trying to deploy Vault Warden server which is requiring the full pem chain and rsa key.

Using OpenSSL I entered:

<openssl genrsa -in mycert.pem -out privkey.pem>

and I get an error "genrsa: Unknown ciper in"

I only use OpenSSL about once a year so I know I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to recover your private key from a certificate?  That can't be done.  Public keys are created from private keys, and certificates are just signed public keys with metadata attached.  What exactly are you trying to do?